# has anybody the trac report to get all tickets without milestone?

Tags: trac, report, milestone

i'm looking for the TracQuery for the trac report to get all tickets without assigned milestone listed. have you already composed this query, if yes, would you share it? thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it, adapt to suit your precise needs....

```
SELECT 
   id AS ticket,
   datetime(time,'unixepoch'),
   summary,
   status,
   priority,
   description AS _description
  FROM ticket t
  WHERE t.milestone is NULL AND t.status<>'closed'
  ORDER BY time desc, status, severity, summary
```

The key part for you is simply to filter on the milestone being NULL.

Comment: i  tried this, but this ends in a "No matches found." altought there are tickets without milestones around.

Comment: This worked for me. You might need to go and explore your trac database by hand with the sqlite3 client to see what values your problem tickets have got for their milestone.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the 'No matches found' for the answer by Paul Dixon, so I tried it on my own:

```
SELECT 
   id AS ticket,
   time AS date,
   summary,
   status,
   priority,
   description AS _description
  FROM ticket t
  WHERE t.milestone not in (
    SELECT name
      FROM milestone
    )
    AND t.status<>'closed'
  ORDER BY time desc, status, severity, summary
```

Note: Trac has some "magic" result table column names. Assigning 'date' will do the appropriate conversation of time stamp integer to date string automagically - even better - respecting the current internal Trac time stamp format of POSIX **micro**-seconds (since Trac 0.12) too. In this respect the SQL statement above is even the most portable solution I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple using Trac's query language instead of raw SQL.  On a wiki page, you can use `query:milestone=` to create a link to a query of all tickets without a milestone assigned.  Invoke the macro `[[TicketQuery(milestone=)]]` to insert the list of matching tickets into the wiki page.

To do the same thing on the "Custom Query" page, remove all search criteria and add a single criteria of "milestone" "is" and leave the third field blank.